# Creating subplots from a list of sub dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I'm working on a project for video game sales on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/gregorut/videogamesales).

The first 5 records of this data are (taken out a few columns for space):

```
        Name                Platform    Genre        Publisher  NA_Sales    EU_Sales    JP_Sales    Global_Sales
0   Wii Sports                Wii      Sports        Nintendo   41.49       29.02        3.77        82.74
1   Super Mario Bros.         NES      Platform      Nintendo   29.08       3.58         6.81        40.24
2   Mario Kart Wii            Wii      Racing        Nintendo   15.85       12.88        3.79        35.82
3   Wii Sports Resort         Wii      Sports        Nintendo   15.75       11.01        3.28        33.00
4   Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue  GB       Role-Playing  Nintendo   11.27       8.89         10.22       31.37
```

What I wish to do is compare Sony and Nintendo genre sales by `Platform`(console). So what I have done so far is firstly create Sony `sub dataframes` by doing `sony_spt = sony.loc[sony['Genre']=='Sports'].drop(columns=['Year', 'Publisher'])` for e.g., and then `plot`.
This example creates the `plot`:

```
# Sony sports sub df
sony_spt.groupby('Platform').sum().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 7))

plt.xlabel('Platform')
plt.ylabel('Sales in $1m\'s')
plt.title('Sony sales in games per console for Sports genre')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have put the rest of my sub `dataframes` that I have gathered for Nintendo and Sony in a `list`. For example again my sony genre list is `sony_genre_list = [sony_spt, sony_msc, sony_puz, sony_sim, sony_sgy, sony_ftg, sony_adv, sony_rpy, sony_sht, sony_rac, sony_plt, sony_act]`. All the genre's listed are: sport, misc, puzzles, simulation, strategy, fighting, adventure, role-play, shooting, racing, platform games and action.

How can I save time and make `subplots` (like the one I've demonstrated) of this `list` of `sub df's` to compare genre sales per console/platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `zip`:

```
sony_genre_list = [sony_spt, sony_msc, sony_puz, sony_sim, sony_sgy, sony_ftg, sony_adv, sony_rpy, sony_sht, sony_rac, sony_plt, sony_act]

# custumize nrows, ncols, figsize
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(sony_genre_list), ncols=1, 
                         figsize=(7,30))

for df, ax in zip(sony_genre_list, axes.ravel()):
    df.groupby('Platform').sum().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
```

You can also bypass the creation of `sony_genre_list` with `groupby`:

```
for genre, df in sony.groupby('Genre'):
    ax = df.groupby('Platform').sum().plot(kind='bar')
```